# How to save integers from map to using the for loop

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have a question to you, I am trying to save integers from map to an array using for loop. This example below is not working as I wanted, because when I display that array of ints it only have '2' for 10 elements, but I wanted to get [1,2,0,0,0,0...], what should be changed in that code?

```
Map<Integer, String> fooMap = new HashMap<>();
fooMap.put(1, "AB");
fooMap.put(2, "BBA");

int[] arrayOfIntegers = new int[10];

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> values : fooMap.entrySet()) {
    int val = values.getKey();
    System.out.println(val);
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayOfIntegers.length; index++) {
        arrayOfIntegers[index] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: You loop around all the entries (1 -> AB and 2 -> BBA), print the key (1 and 2) and then write that key to every index of an array that is never read. What's confusing you about it?

Comment: For each element in the map, you're iterating over the entire array and setting each index in it to the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop you overwrite the entire array. You could instead save the array's index outside the loop and use it to update the array:

```
int index = 0;
for (Integer val: fooMap.keySet()) {
    arrayOfIntegers[index] = val;
    ++index;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams:

```
int[] arrayOfIntegers = fooMap.keySet().stream()
                              .mapToInt(k->k).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class stack1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Map<Integer, String> fooMap = new HashMap<>();
     fooMap.put(1, "AB");
     fooMap.put(2, "BBA");

     int memoryAllocated = 10;
     int[] arrayOfIntegers = new int[memoryAllocated];
     int pos =0;

     for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> values : fooMap.entrySet()) {
         int val = values.getKey();
         arrayOfIntegers[pos]=val;
         pos =pos+1;
     }

     while(pos < memoryAllocated){
         arrayOfIntegers[pos]=0;
         pos = pos+1;
     }

     System.out.println("Arrays : "+Arrays.toString(arrayOfIntegers));
}
}
```